# Pode-se distribuir programa com Licença GPL junto com não GPL

Tags: licença, gpl

Acredito que isso faz parte do nosso [escopo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/264/quais-assuntos-devem-fazer-parte-do-nosso-foco-on-topic) (penúltimo item).

**Minha dúvida é a seguinte:**

Se eu criar um programa (Interface Gráfica) que comunique (de forma dinâmica) com um programa GPL, poderia distribuir os dois juntos ? *[Sei que se for comunicação estática é uma infração da licença]*

Claro que espeficicando a lincença de cada, os direitos permitidos aos usuários etc.

Answer (score 6):

> **Alerta:** não tenho conhecimento profundo de licenças e leis, portanto não considere esta resposta como definitiva do ponto de vista legal. Na dúvida, consulte um advogado especializado.

---

A FAQ da licença GPL apresenta o conceito de [***"mera agregação"***](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#MereAggregation), isto é, dois programas lado a lado no mesmo disco, mas separados, não sendo parte de um único programa.

Segundo a FAQ:

> Neste caso, se um dos programas é coberto pela GPL, isso não tem efeito no outro programa.

O motivo é simples:

> *Pipes*, *sockets* e argumentos de linha de comando são mecanismos de comunicação normalmente utilizados entre programas separados

Mas note que os programas não poderiam ser colocados num mesmo instalador, pois:

> Se os módulos são incluídos no mesmo arquivo executável, então eles estão definitivamente combinados em um único programa.

O mesmo vale se os dois programas usarem um endereço de memória compartilhado, isto é, eles seriam consideradas um único programa.

Enfim, imagino um cenário possível para combinar GPL e alguma licença menos restritiva:

1. Usuário recebe um disco ou um ZIP contendo dois arquivos de instalação, o do programa principal não-GPL outro do programa secundário GPL.
2. A instalação do programa principal não-GPL, após encerrar, executa a instalação do programa GPL em um processo separado.
3. Os dois programas ficam em diretórios separados, como dois aplicativos independentes no sistema operacional.
4. O programa não-GPL pode fazer chamadas ao programa GPL, via API do sistema operacional, utilizando parâmetros, *pipes*, *sockets* e outros recursos comuns de comunicação.

O que não pode ser feito, por exemplo, é carregar um módulo ou DLL de um programa no outro.

Comment: É bom frisar que essa é a interpretação que a FSF dá para o que é uma "obra derivada". A justiça pode interpretar diferente (seja a favor do autor do software GPL, seja a favor de quem o redistribuiu "irregularmente") - inclusive países diferentes podem aplicar as leis de modo diferente. A **intenção** conta muito, ao contrário do nosso senso comum [de que a justiça é uma coisa rígida, que vale o que está no papel e pronto], e se os propósitos dos dois sistemas são próximos ou distantes. de todo modo, as informações apresentadas aqui estão corretas - e bem próximas do que ocorreria na prática.

Comment: Um bom exemplo é o BlueZ (Pilha Bluetooth para Linux), que é GPL e implementa toda sua API em cima do D-Bus justamente para não "contaminar" programas que vão usar Bluetooth com a licença GPL.

Answer (score 1):

Conforme consta no [FAQ da GPL](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#GPLCompatInstaller)

> The installer and the files it installs are separate works. As a result, the terms of the GPL do not apply to the installation software.

Ou seja:

> O instalativo e os arquivos que o mesmo instala são trabalhos separados. Como resultado os termos da GPL não se applicam ao programa de instalação.

Para o **meu** entendimento sequer o instalativo deve seguir a GPL. Portanto pode-se sim incluir programas GPL junto com não GPL sem que o não GPL caia nos termos dessa licença mas é importante deixar claro que o programa não livre precisará obrigatóriamente comunicar-se com o GPL (quando o fizer) por:

- Pipe
- Sockets
- interface de linha de comando.

Essa resposta é uma adaptação [dessa resposta](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/252981/130078) do [Doc Brown](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/9113/doc-brown) no Programmers.SE

* *Referente ao entendimento do autor original*