# Qual licença escolher, MIT, Apache, GPL?

Tags: licença

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em PHP, quero liberar ela de modo que, qualquer pessoa possa baixar o código, melhorar ou até mesmo construir soluções derivadas...

Essas pessoas poderão vender o produto final sobre qualquer outra licença. Vi que se eu liberar meu código como GPL, terceiros terão que fazer o mesmo.

Qual licença me permite disponibilizar o meu código/software de modo que terceiros possam incorpora-lo a seus produtos e até disponibilizar sobre uma licença fechada?

Comment: Relacionadas: [Posso usar MIT junto com GPL?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44862/91), [Pode-se distribuir programa com Licença GPL junto com não GPL](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23755/91) e [Como funciona o licenciamento de software no Brasil](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/76564/91)

Comment: Qual você acha que responde sua pergunta? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/139465/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/76564/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/59904/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/46063/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44862/101 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/29789/101

Comment: Se quer deixar livre, acho que MIT seria a mais livre de todas. Sugiro que dê uma lida em: [Which License Should I Use? MIT vs. Apache vs. GPL](http://exygy.com/which-license-should-i-use-mit-vs-apache-vs-gpl/) E sobre a GPL, tem uma pergunta bem interessante aqui no site, que apesar de estar fechada, acho que vale dar uma lida: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/153124/31016